# How to find out which targets are supported by a ppa?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, arm

I am searching for a way to find out which targets are supported by a specific ppa.

**Simplified Example**

I need to install the seafile client on a arm target. So I added its ppa, updated and tried to install it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:seafile/seafile-client
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install seafile-gui
```

Well, then I get the error: `Unable to locate package`

**How I tried to see supported targets:**

Someone told me, that arm is not supported by this ppa. How can I know about this?

1. I tried taking a look to launchpad, where I found a hint, that i286 and amd64 are supported only: [image: Screenshot of the ppa on launchpad]
2. I entered the URL, which is shown during apt-get update into my browser: `http://ppa.launchpad.net/seafile/seafile-client/ubuntu/`. Navigating through the different folders, I found an armhf amd an arm64 folder next to the amd64 and the i386 folder here:

   ```
   http://ppa.launchpad.net/seafile/seafile-client/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-armhf/
   http://ppa.launchpad.net/seafile/seafile-client/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-arm64/
   ```

   All folders are filled with similar files. So is the arm target nevertheless supported?

**Question**

How do I find out which targets are supported by a ppa?

Answer (score 1):

Afaik Launchpad PPAs only include binary packages for the architectures listed on the web page of their respective source package (like in the screenshot in your question).

If you want to investigate further you can download and inspect the relevant [`Packages` index file](http://ppa.launchpad.net/seafile/seafile-client/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-armhf/Packages.gz):

```
$ wget -O - 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/seafile/seafile-client/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-armhf/Packages.gz' | zcat | grep -Ee '^(Package|Architecture): '
Package: python-searpc
Architecture: all
```

For this PPA it will list only architecture-independent packages, i. e. those with the architecture `all` that contain no hardware-specific machine code instructions.